# System/Convention for code-independent serialization

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I'm training neural networks.  I want to save them in a code-independent way so they can be loaded by someone using different software.

Just pickling my objects is no good, because the pickle breaks if it's loaded in an environment where the code has changed or moved (which it always does).

So I've been converting my objects into dicts of primitive types and pickling those.  I maintain a module that can convert these dicts back into objects (the type of object is defined by a "class" key of the dict).  My current solution feels messy.

So I was wondering if there's some package or design pattern that's made to handle this kind of "code-independent serialization"

Comment: You'll need to separate the storage format from the runtime format (some kind of strength reduction perhaps all the way down to a json dialect -- or some binary format if size matters). Then you need to separate the serialization code so it gets a stable api. The api needs to  be versioned, and whenever you create a new version (a) the old version needs to stay so you can read old files, and (b) you need a function to upgrade version x to version x+1 (read old files, write new files).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy/scipy for your project, you could save your weight matrixes in [matlab format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html).

Comment: Well yes, I can also pickle them... My problem is more about what is the best practice for storing a more complex structure (eg a convolutional network) so it can be loaded from file, but still independent of code.